Fourier transform with and without convolution theorem not equivalent
This is a problem involving Fourier transforming an integral relevant to the computation of Feynman diagrams, which is of the form:
$S(r_1,r_2)=\int d^3 r_3 \space v(r_1,r_3)f(r_3,r_2),$ where $v(r_1,r_2)=\frac{1}{|r_1-r_2|}$, and all $r_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$.
If we consider that $v(r_1,r_2)=v(r_1-r_2)$, then the integral above becomes a convolution in real space, and the Fourier transform of both sides will give:
$\mathcal{F}[S](k_1,k_2)=\tilde v (k_1)\tilde f(k_1,k_2),$ with $\tilde v(k)=\frac{1}{k^2}$, ignoring constants.
This result should be equivalent to one obtained when ignoring that $v(r_1,r_2)=v(r_1-r_2)$ until the end:
$S(r_1,r_2)=\int d^3 r_3 \space v(r_1,r_3)f(r_3,r_2).$
$S(r_1,r_2)=\lim_{k_3\rightarrow0^+}\int d^3 r_3 \space e^{i k_3 . r_3}v(r_1,r_3)f(r_3,r_2).$
$\begin{align} \mathcal{F}[S](k_1,k_2)&= [\int d^3 k \space \tilde v(k_1,k_3-k)\tilde f(k,k_2) ]|_{k_3=0}\\
&= \int d^3 k \space \tilde v(k_1,-k)\tilde f(k,k_2)\\ &= \int d^3 k \space \tilde v(k_1 + k)\tilde f(k,k_2)\end{align}$
I can't find a way to show that this is equivalent to the simple product above, or where I've made a mistake. I've been led to believe that $\tilde v(k_1,k_2)=\frac{1}{|k_1-k_2|^2}$, though maybe that is incorrect.

You forgot the extra Dirac delta:$$\tilde v(k_1,k_2)=\frac{\delta(k_1-k_2)}{k_1^2}$$ Indeed, $v$ is invariant by translation so is diagonal in Fourier space.
